# Browser displays nothing when I try to pass the data from one component to another -React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning react and javascript .I am trying to build a Meetup application .The folder structure is shown below:
[image]

In AllMeetups.js,I have the data and I use the Meetuplist to pass the values.

```
import Meetuplist from "../components/Meetups/Meetuplist";

const DUMMY_DATA = [
    {
      id: 'm1',
      title: 'This is a first meetup',
      
    },
    {
      id: 'm2',
      title: 'This is a second meetup',
    },         
  ];
function AllMeetupspage(){
return <section>
    <h1>AllMeetups</h1>     
    <Meetuplist meetups={DUMMY_DATA} />             //I pass MeetupList          
    </section>

}

export default AllMeetupspage;
```

In Meetuplist.js,I pass values to Meetupitem

```
import Meetupitem from "./Meetupitem";
import classes from "./Meetuplistmodule.css";

function Meetuplist(props) {
  return (
    <ul className={classes.list}>
      {props.meetups.map((meetup) => (
        <Meetupitem                           //I use MeetupItem
          key={meetup.id}
          id={meetup.id}
          title={meetup.title}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
export default Meetuplist;
```

In Meetupitem.js,

```
import classes from './Meetupitemmodule.css';


function Meetupitem(props){
    return <li className={classes.item}>
        <div className={classes.image}>
            <img src={props.image} alt={props.title}></img>

        </div>
        <div className={classes.content}>
            <h3>{props.title}</h3>
        </div>
        <div className={classes.actions}>
            <button>To Favourites</button>
        </div>
    </li>

}
export default Meetupitem;
```

I get this error in the console.

```
react-dom.development.js:14169 Uncaught Error: Meetuplist(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.
    at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js:14169)
    at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js:16990)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17890)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19049)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707)
react-dom.development.js:20085 The above error occurred in the <Meetuplist> component:

    at Meetuplist
    at section
    at AllMeetupspage
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35900:5)
    at div
    at App
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35833:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35313:5)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:20085
bootstrap:27 Uncaught Error: Meetuplist(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.
    at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js:14169)
    at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js:16990)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17890)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19049)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707)
```

I think in AllMeetup.js ,the way I pass `<Meetuplist meetups={DUMMY_DATA} />`  is wrong but I am not sure.

Also,my app.js file is shown below where I call AllMeetuppage

```
import { Route,Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import AllMeetupspage from './pages/AllMeetups';
import Favouritespage from './pages/Favourites';

import NewmeetupPage from './pages/Newmeetup';
import Mainnavigationcomponent from './components/layout/Mainnavigationcomponent';

function App() {
  return (
    
    <div>
      <Mainnavigationcomponent/>
      <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<AllMeetupspage />}/>
      
      <Route path='/new-meetup' element={<NewmeetupPage />}/>
      <Route path='/Favouritespage' element={<Favouritespage />}/>
     
      </Routes>  
   
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Also,when I use

```
{DUMMY_DATA.map(item=><li>{item.title}</li>)}
```

instead of `<Meetuplist meetups={DUMMY_DATA} />` ,I get the result.I am not sure where I go wrong.

Comment: There's no error in the console (development tools) of your browser? For example, `props.image` in your `Meetupitem` component almost certainly doesn't exist according to the code you've posted.

Comment: Are you rendering the AllMeetupspage component inside the App.js component?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the way you're passing the DUMMY_DATA in as a prop. Infact I ran your code and it completely works (I ran it without your css classes). Where do you call <AllMeetupsPage /> ? And does it show if you return simply a <h1>Test</h1> from it?

Comment: @BenRipka I have added app.js where I call the <AllMeetupspage>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4827845/joshua-jones. -Yes

Answer (score 0):

The reason you see a blank page in React is there is some error in your code. Open your console in browser and you will find the exact errors.

Comment: Yes...I am able to see the error now and I have edited my question.

Comment: In all meetups page, try enclosing the return statement with braces. If that doesn't work, can you push your code in GitHub and share the link

Comment: I tried adding the braces.Still its the same..I have pushed the code to github and here is the link:     https://github.com/suchitraa/React.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/11581301/gokul-nath -Is there any other way to pass the data to another component?I have looked into other articles as well.I am not able to find any solution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).